# Can't play a YouTube video in tvOS. Got a "Operation requires a client data source to have been registered"

Tags: swift, youtube, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

When I try to play a YouTube video in tvOS I get the following error:

> [MediaRemote] [MRPlaybackQueueServiceClient] playbackQueueRequest
>   AFCF4995-D293-4B5B-82F0-E701186F639F PineBoard-21384
>   /A600.000000x600.000000/R[0:1] responded to asset request with error
>   Error Domain=kMRMediaRemoteFrameworkErrorDomain Code=15 "Operation
>   requires a client data source to have been registered."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation requires a client data
>   source to have been registered.}

I'm using the XCDYouTubeKit library.

The code where the error is produced is:

```
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

weak var weakPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController? = playerViewController

XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier("9bZkp7q19f0") { video, error in
      if (video != nil) {
          let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs
          var streamURL: URL?

          if (streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] != nil) { streamURL = streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] }
          else if (streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue] != nil) { streamURL = streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue] }
          else if (streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue] != nil) { streamURL = streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue] }
          else if (streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240.rawValue] != nil) { streamURL = streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240.rawValue] }

          if let streamURL = streamURL {
              weakPlayerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
              weakPlayerViewController?.player?.play() // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
          }
      }
  }
```

I don't understand why I get this error.
Even, If I run the tvOS demo code inside the XCDYouTubeKit repository I also get the same error.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, by the moment. What I've experienced is that the same code works on my MBP, but no on my MacMini :-(

Comment: I do have the same issue playing local video files on a appleTV.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following to appDelegate.swift should fix the error:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .moviePlayback)
    }
    catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
    return true
}
```